# Chrome Dev Tools - Can't Click On Elements Anymore?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For some reason in the latest versions of Canary (and I reinstalled it a couple times) no longer allows you to change elements in dev tools by clicking on them. The only way I can go through the DOM in the elements tab is with the up and down arrow keys which takes forever.

I can use the magnifying glass to select things, but then can't go further into their children elements without using the arrow key. Clicking on elements does nothing at all.

How to fix?

Comment: I am experiencing this too, on the up-to-date Chrome Beta (40.0.2214.28 beta (64-bit)). This is the only mention I was able to find of the issue. It's a tricky thing to Google.

Comment: Not quite sure how this isn't driving everybody else nuts! lol

Comment: I have this problem with Chrome `45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)` and it's absurdly irritating. The only solution I found is to restart multiple times... Please Google, look into this...

Answer (score 8):

I was seeing this too... seems devtools can get in a funky state. The solution is to:

1. open devtools
2. click the `traffic light icon` and click `Settings`
3. scroll down and click `Restore defaults and reload` button

This fixed it for me...

Comment: it worked. thanks friend.

Comment: Where is the `traffic light icon`?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. I noticed that although you can't click on the element itself, you can on the white space on the left of it, with the same effect.